# Cookie cannot be retrieved when re-visit the page

Tags: asp.net, ios, vb.net, session, cookies

I have got a web application (written by ASP.NET, VB.NET and javascript) stores the cookie "session_key" when doing the log in. After the authentication is approved, the application then jumps to next page. On the next page, there is a function to get and check the cookie "session_key" to ensure the user has been logged in previously within a reasonable time. This algorithm is working great from the first day across different browsers as well as iPhone/iPad and Android.

Unfortunately since some of our users have upgraded their iPhone/iPad to iOS6, This algorithm is not working on their device at all. The user can log in the application at the first time perfectly, however after they log out and log back in, the cookie "session_key" cannot be retrieved anymore.

I have traced the code and found that the "session_key" is stored in the log in page after the authentication is done, but it is gone when the application jump to the next page, and there is only "ASP.NET_cookie" in the browser instead.

This issue only occurs on iOS6 not iOS5 for both Wifi or 3G connection, so it is not about the Wifi bugs on iOS6.

Can somebody help? Any advance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been solved!!

This is because of the Safari on iOS6 caches the function with the parameters value, so Safari does call the function from memory if all parameters value are same.

To resolve the problem, a timestamp is required to pass into the function, so the value of the parameters is different, it results the Safari calls the function from the server again instead of from the memory.